# How can I correct where my apps point to my schema.prisma in a turbo repo

Tags: typescript, webpack, next.js, prisma, turborepo

I have a turbo repo which has a database package containing my prisma client. Currently I am importing it into my next app just fine, the issue is with my cli app. The cli app needs the prisma client as well, but when I import it it says it cannot find the schema.prisma. How would you go about pointing it to the right schema.prisma?

Here is a simple recreation: https://github.com/bmdavis419/mono-repo-prisma-help-please

EDIT: https://turbo.build/repo/docs/handbook/prisma#guide

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Were you able to find a solution to this?